# Can we use Parameter mode directly inside BEGIN part?

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE do_something(p_a IN OUT VARCHAR2)
AS

BEGIN
p_a := 'something';
END;
/
Procedure created.

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> VARIABLE a VARCHAR2(30)
SQL> exec do_something(:a);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

While am execute above procedure, it wont show output called `something` from procedure. What is the reason, what is happening backend?

Comment: Did you mean: `p_a := 'something';`?

Comment: @GMB yes, there literal will come.

Comment: Naveen, you did not print the var to see something, neither dbms_output.put_line, not print a in sqlplus. set serveroutput on let's sqlplus display what you put in dbms_output.put_line, not what your 'variable's has

Answer (score 1):

The variable holds the value you've assigned in your session context. You can use SQL*Plus PRINT to see it:

> SQL> PRINT :a;